# Запуск Angular проекта

Tags: angular

Изучаю Angular. Создал небольшой проект в IDEA. Запускаю его командой

```
ng serve --open
```

У меня появилось несколько вопросов

1. Чтобы мне запустить его на другом компе, какие файлы мне надо туда перекинуть?  Не весь же проект мне переносить.
2. Правильно я понимаю, что для работы этого проекта вполне достаточно Node.js или лучше использовать другой сервер?
3. Я хочу чтобы этот проект был все время запущен, т.е. стартовал при запуске винды. Как это правильно делается. Каждый раз запускать команду **ng serve** или можно его как-то задеплоить на сервер?

Answer (score 2):

1. Команда ng build соберет для вас выходной каталог dist, который уже переносится куда нужно.
2. Какой вы будете использовать сервер не важно для фронта, ему главное получать свои файлы в папках сервера.
3. Это можно сделать разными путями, почитайте как автоматически поднимать сервер при запуске винды: pm2; или bat в автозапуске; или qckwinsvc;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445599/auto-start-node-js-server-on-boot